# Best way to divide in bash using pipes?

Tags: linux, bash, math

I'm just looking for an easy way to divide a number (or provide other math functions). Let's say I have the following command:

```
find . -name '*.mp4' | wc -l
```

How can I take the result of wc -l and divide it by 3?

The examples I've seen don't deal with re-directed out/in.

Comment: note that bash cannot do floating point math.

Comment: I think I've found ***The best way to divide in bash using pipes!*** See recently added *`shell connector`* in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13182139/1765658)

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter with 64bits integer, [tag:bash] could do pseudo *floating-point* with enough precision in many case!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Using `bc`:

```
$ bc -l <<< "scale=2;$(find . -name '*.mp4' | wc -l)/3"
2.33
```

In contrast, the bash shell only performs integer arithmetic.

Awk is also very powerful:

```
$ find . -name '*.mp4' | wc -l | awk '{print $1/3}'
2.33333
```

You don't even need `wc` if using `awk`:

```
$ find . -name '*.mp4' | awk 'END {print NR/3}'
2.33333
```

Comment: How would you assign the awk `2.333` to a variable?

Comment: `your_variable=$(find . -name '*.mp4' | awk 'END {print NR/3}')`

Comment: awk is much slower than wc though, so `(...) | wc -l | awk 'END {print $1/3}'` would be preferred, no?

Answer (score 12):

**Edit 2018-02-22: Adding `shell connector`**

## There is more than 1 way:

Depending on precision required **and** number of calcul to be done! See *`shell connector`* further!

### Using `bc` (binary calculator)

```
find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -printf \\n | wc -l | xargs printf "%d/3\n" | bc -l
6243.33333333333333333333
```

or

```
echo $(find . -name '*.mp4' -printf \\n | wc -l)/3|bc -l
6243.33333333333333333333
```

or using bash, result in integer only:

```
echo $(($(find . -name '*.mp4' -printf \\n| wc -l)/3))
6243
```

### Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) interger builtin math processor

```
res=000$((($(find  . -type f -name '*.mp4' -printf "1+")0)*1000/3))
printf -v res "%.2f" ${res:0:${#res}-3}.${res:${#res}-3}
echo $res
6243.33
```

### Pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

With recent 64bits bash, you could even use [@glennjackman's ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13183567/1765658) of using `globstar`, but computing pseudo floating could be done by:

```
shopt -s globstar
files=(**/*.mp4)
shopt -u globstar
res=$[${#files[*]}000/3]
printf -v res "%.2f" ${res:0:${#res}-3}.${res:${#res}-3}
echo $res
6243.33
```

There is no fork and `$res` contain a two digit rounded floating value.

**Nota**: Care about *symlinks* when using `globstar` and `**`!

## Introducing *`shell connector`*

If you plan to do a lot of calculs, require high precision and use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could use ***long running `bc` sub process***:

```
mkfifo /tmp/mybcfifo
exec 5> >(exec bc -l >/tmp/mybcfifo)
exec 6</tmp/mybcfifo
rm /tmp/mybcfifo
```

then now:

```
echo >&5 '12/34'
read -u 6 result
echo $result
.35294117647058823529
```

This subprocess stay open and useable:

```
ps --sid $(ps ho sid $$) fw
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
18027 pts/9    Ss     0:00 bash
18258 pts/9    S      0:00  \_ bc -l
18789 pts/9    R+     0:00  \_ ps --sid 18027 fw
```

Computing `$PI`:

```
echo >&5 '4*a(1)'
read -u 6 PI
echo $PI
3.14159265358979323844
```

To terminate sub process:

```
exec 6<&-
exec 5>&-
```

### Little demo, about *The best way to divide in bash using pipes!*

Computing range `{1..157} / 42` ( I will let you google for *`answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything`* ;)

... and print 13 result by lines in order to reduce output:

```
printf -v form "%s" "%5.3f "{,}{,}{,,};form+="%5.3f\n";
```

By regular way

```
testBc(){
    for ((i=1; i<157; i++)) ;do
        echo $(bc -l <<<"$i/42");
    done
}
```

By using *long running `bc` sub process*:

```
testLongBc(){ 
    mkfifo /tmp/mybcfifo;
    exec 5> >(exec bc -l >/tmp/mybcfifo);
    exec 6< /tmp/mybcfifo;
    rm /tmp/mybcfifo;
    for ((i=1; i<157; i++)) ;do
        echo "$i/42" 1>&5;
        read -u 6 result;
        echo $result;
    done;
    exec 6>&-;
    exec 5>&-
}
```

Let's see *without*:

```
time printf "$form" $(testBc)
0.024 0.048 0.071 0.095 0.119 0.143 0.167 0.190 0.214 0.238 0.262 0.286 0.310
0.333 0.357 0.381 0.405 0.429 0.452 0.476 0.500 0.524 0.548 0.571 0.595 0.619
0.643 0.667 0.690 0.714 0.738 0.762 0.786 0.810 0.833 0.857 0.881 0.905 0.929
0.952 0.976 1.000 1.024 1.048 1.071 1.095 1.119 1.143 1.167 1.190 1.214 1.238
1.262 1.286 1.310 1.333 1.357 1.381 1.405 1.429 1.452 1.476 1.500 1.524 1.548
1.571 1.595 1.619 1.643 1.667 1.690 1.714 1.738 1.762 1.786 1.810 1.833 1.857
1.881 1.905 1.929 1.952 1.976 2.000 2.024 2.048 2.071 2.095 2.119 2.143 2.167
2.190 2.214 2.238 2.262 2.286 2.310 2.333 2.357 2.381 2.405 2.429 2.452 2.476
2.500 2.524 2.548 2.571 2.595 2.619 2.643 2.667 2.690 2.714 2.738 2.762 2.786
2.810 2.833 2.857 2.881 2.905 2.929 2.952 2.976 3.000 3.024 3.048 3.071 3.095
3.119 3.143 3.167 3.190 3.214 3.238 3.262 3.286 3.310 3.333 3.357 3.381 3.405
3.429 3.452 3.476 3.500 3.524 3.548 3.571 3.595 3.619 3.643 3.667 3.690 3.714

real    0m10.113s
user    0m0.900s
sys     0m1.290s
```

Wow! **Ten seconds** on my raspberry-pi!!

Then *with*:

```
time printf "$form" $(testLongBc)
0.024 0.048 0.071 0.095 0.119 0.143 0.167 0.190 0.214 0.238 0.262 0.286 0.310
0.333 0.357 0.381 0.405 0.429 0.452 0.476 0.500 0.524 0.548 0.571 0.595 0.619
0.643 0.667 0.690 0.714 0.738 0.762 0.786 0.810 0.833 0.857 0.881 0.905 0.929
0.952 0.976 1.000 1.024 1.048 1.071 1.095 1.119 1.143 1.167 1.190 1.214 1.238
1.262 1.286 1.310 1.333 1.357 1.381 1.405 1.429 1.452 1.476 1.500 1.524 1.548
1.571 1.595 1.619 1.643 1.667 1.690 1.714 1.738 1.762 1.786 1.810 1.833 1.857
1.881 1.905 1.929 1.952 1.976 2.000 2.024 2.048 2.071 2.095 2.119 2.143 2.167
2.190 2.214 2.238 2.262 2.286 2.310 2.333 2.357 2.381 2.405 2.429 2.452 2.476
2.500 2.524 2.548 2.571 2.595 2.619 2.643 2.667 2.690 2.714 2.738 2.762 2.786
2.810 2.833 2.857 2.881 2.905 2.929 2.952 2.976 3.000 3.024 3.048 3.071 3.095
3.119 3.143 3.167 3.190 3.214 3.238 3.262 3.286 3.310 3.333 3.357 3.381 3.405
3.429 3.452 3.476 3.500 3.524 3.548 3.571 3.595 3.619 3.643 3.667 3.690 3.714

real    0m0.670s
user    0m0.190s
sys     0m0.070s
```

Less than **one second**!!

Hopefully, results are same, but execution time is very different!

### My `shell connector`

I've published a connector function: [Connector-bash on GitHub.com](https://github.com/F-Hauri/Connector-bash)
 and [shell_connector.sh on my own site](http://f-hauri.ch/vrac/shell_connector.sh).

```
source shell_connector.sh
newConnector /usr/bin/bc -l 0 0
myBc 1764/42 result
echo $result
42.00000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 6):

`find . -name '*.mp4' | wc -l | xargs -I{} expr {} / 2`

Best used if you have multiple outputs you'd like to pipe through `xargs`. Use`{}` as a placeholder for the expression term.

Comment: Results in an integer, not a float.

Comment: I had a slightly different problem, but: `find . | grep -v /old/ | wc -l | xargs -I{} expr {} - 2` Works like a charm for my needs!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your bash version, you don't even need find for this simple task:

```
shopt -s nullglob globstar
files=( **/*.mp4 )
dc -e "3 k ${#files[@]} 3 / p"
```

This method will correctly handle the bizarre edgecase of filenames containing newlines.

Comment: Good idea(+1), but if `bash`, why `dc` ? (care about symlinks when working with globstar). see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13182139/1765658)

Comment: I'm not that hardcore about prohitibing external processes. Shells were created to be glue languages. Doing floating point math with strings is hideous. If you need a calculator, use a calculator -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy

Comment: You could avoid bad count by filename containing newline by `find  . -type f -name '*.mp4' -printf \\n|wc -l`  or  `echo $(($(find  . -type f -name '*.mp4' -printf "1+")0))`