# How to find a specific portion of a string using a regular expression in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I would like to find a specific portion of a string using a regular expression in bash. Additionally, I would like to store that portion in another bash variable.
By searching in the web, I could find one solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

string="aaa.ddd.config.uuu"
result=`expr match "$string" '\(.*\)\.config.*'`
echo $result
```

In the above case, I would like to find out the portion before `"\.config"` and want to store in another variable named `result`.
Is the above one a good and efficient approach?
I would like to know what would be a recommended way in such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Avoid bash regex when not needed

Use:

```
result=${string%.config*}
```

Not only quicker, but more *POSIX compliant*.

Tests:

```
string="aaa.ddd.config.uuu"

time for ((i=30000;i--;)){ [[ $string =~ (.*)\.config ]] && result=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ;}

real    0m1.331s
user    0m1.313s
sys     0m0.000s

echo $result 
aaa.ddd
```

Ok

```
time for ((i=30000;i--;)){ result=${string%.config*} ;}

real    0m0.226s
user    0m0.224s
sys     0m0.000s

echo $result 
aaa.ddd
```

For this, bash regex will take 5.8x more resources than simple *Parameter Expansion*!

Comment: Parameter expansion is excellent. The BASH_REMATCH is much better than an external solution like `sed 's/[.]config.*//' <<< "${string}"`.

Comment: @WalterA Depending on size of files to work on! Using dedicated tasks to do specialized function (like `sed`) permit parallelization, then become much more quick! Have a look at [best way to divide in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13182139/1765658) for a sample of dedicated parallel task!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bash` built-in regular expressions and the array variable `BASH_REMATCH` that captures the results of a regular expression match:

```
$ string="aaa.ddd.config.uuu"
$ [[ $string =~ (.*)\.config ]] && result=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} 
$ echo $result
aaa.ddd
```